# How to avoid form getting refreshed using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jQuery Ajax to submit a form and display the status message. But the form is getting refreshed on submit. How can I prevent this.
HTML -

```
<head>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function(event) { //Trigger on form submit                 
                    $('#stage').empty();

                    var postForm = {//Fetch form data
                        "firstname": $("#input-835541607580400877").val(),
                        "lastname": $("#input-835541607580400877-1").val(),
                        "email": $("#input-784767378242468265").val(),
                        "countrycode": $("#input-756058593620931363").val(),
                        "statecode": $("#input-756058593620931363-1").val(),
                        "number": $("#input-756058593620931363-2").val(),                        
                        "message": $("#input-127588635592794719").val(),                       
                    };

                    $.ajax({//Process the form using $.ajax()
                        type: 'POST', //Method type
                        url: 'contact.php', //Your form processing file url
                        data: postForm, //Forms name
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log("inside success3");
                            console.log(data);

                            if (data.status == "success") {
                                $("#stage").html("Thank you for your message.");
                                $("#input-835541607580400877").val("");
                                $("#input-835541607580400877-1").val("");
                                $("input-784767378242468265").val("");
                                $("#input-993017764288374681").val("");
                                $("#input-993017764288374681-1").val("");
                                $("#input-993017764288374681-2").val("");                        
                                $("#input-127588635592794719").val("");

                            } else {
                                $("#stage").html(data.status);
                            }





                        }
                    });
                    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default submit
                });
            });
        </script>
</head>  

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div id="720750002585596435-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <ul class="formlist" id="720750002585596435-form-list">
      <h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:left;">
        Request for a Quote
        <br />
      </h2>

      <div>
        <div class="wsite-form-field wsite-name-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
          <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-835541607580400877">
            Name 
            <span class="form-required">
              *
            </span>
          </label>
          <div style="clear:both;">
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container wsite-form-left wsite-form-input-first-name">
            <input id="input-835541607580400877" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u835541607580400877[first]" />
            <label class="wsite-form-sublabel" for="input-835541607580400877">
              First
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container wsite-form-right wsite-form-input-last-name">
            <input id="input-835541607580400877-1" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u835541607580400877[last]" />
            <label class="wsite-form-sublabel" for="input-835541607580400877-1">
              Last
            </label>
          </div>
          <div id="instructions-835541607580400877" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="wsite-form-field wsite-phone-field" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;">
          <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-756058593620931363">
            Phone Number 
            <span class="form-required">
              *
            </span>
          </label>
          <div style="clear:both;">
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container wsite-form-left wsite-form-input-phone-first">
            <input id="input-756058593620931363" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input" type="text" name="_u756058593620931363[area_code]" onKeyUp="if(this.value.length==3){document.getElementById('input-756058593620931363-1').focus()}" />
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-phone-separator">
            -
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container wsite-form-left wsite-form-input-phone-second">
            <input id="input-756058593620931363-1" class="wsite-form-input" type="text" name="_u756058593620931363[extension]" onKeyUp="if(this.value.length==3){document.getElementById('input-756058593620931363-2').focus()}" />
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-phone-separator">
            -
          </div>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container wsite-form-right wsite-form-input-phone-third" style="margin-bottom:5px; float:left;">
            <input id="input-756058593620931363-2" class="wsite-form-input" type="text" name="_u756058593620931363[number]" />
          </div>
          <div id="instructions-756058593620931363" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
          <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-784767378242468265">
            Email 
            <span class="form-required">
              *
            </span>
          </label>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
            <input id="input-784767378242468265" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" type="text" name="_u784767378242468265" />
          </div>
          <div id="instructions-784767378242468265" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="wsite-form-field" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
          <label class="wsite-form-label" for="input-127588635592794719">
            Comment 
            <span class="form-required">
              *
            </span>
          </label>
          <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
            <textarea id="input-127588635592794719" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="_u127588635592794719" style="height: 200px">
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <div id="instructions-127588635592794719" class="wsite-form-instructions" style="display:none;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="text" name="wsite_subject" />
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <button type='submit'>
      <span class='wsite-button-inner'>
        Submit
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The form on submit gets refreshed without calling the script. How can I avoid this.

Comment: Add `onsubmit="return false;` to the form tag.

Comment: First off, you don't need two instances of jQuery being loaded.

Comment: @dcclassics could this be a problem

Comment: Op is using `e.preventDefault()` in his JS, he could just replace that with `return false;`.  No need for the inline JS.

Comment: I don't know how it would help.

Comment: No luck on any of this solns

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Before I can see browser console, page gets refreshed

Comment: Check browser's console before you submit the form.

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I tried it, http://jsfiddle.net/AfrFZ/

Comment: You have loaded the `jQuery` twice, different versions, why ? Remove the second `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much more efficient way to do this in my opinion.  I'm not going to copy your code exactly because there is a lot there.  Take your form and have a method dedicated to posting. Here's your javascript... fairly dynamic.  Y

```
//No need to change this code
function postForm(formID, scriptLocation, successCallback){

     var formData = formID.serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: scriptLocation,
       data: formData,
       success: successCallback(formID, data);
     });

}

function successCallback(formID, data){

     //Put your UI code here and access the `data` variable[Change This]



     //This line resets your form [Don't Change This]
     formID[0].reset();

}
```

You can create callback functions and then just pass those onto the for `postForm` function to have one method for posting for your entire web application

Here's the html part:

```
<form onsubmit="postForm($(this), "script.php", successCallback); return false;">

Form Stuff here

</form>
```

So all you need to do is make a function that will be called if the form is submitted successfully.  Then for `onsubmit` change `successCallback` to whatever that function name is but without `()` just like how I have it.  And obviously change `script.php` to whatever it is.